# Retrieve exactly 1 digit using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to print only ages that are less than 10. In this string, only the 
value 1 should be printed. Somehow, that is not happening. 
I used the following codes (using regular expression python)

```
import re

# This is my string

s5 = "The baby is 1 year old, Sri is 45 years old, Ann is 50 years old; 
their father, Sumo is 78 years old and their grandfather, Kris, is 100 years 
old"


# print all the single digits from the string
re.findall('[0-9]{1}', s5)
# Out[153]: ['1', '4', '5', '5', '0', '7', '8', '1', '0', '0']

re.findall('\d{1,1}', s5)
# Out[154]: ['1', '4', '5', '5', '0', '7', '8', '1', '0', '0']

re.findall('\d{1}', s5)
# Out[155]: ['1', '4', '5', '5', '0', '7', '8', '1', '0', '0']
```

The output should be 1 and not all the digits as displayed above.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to match "any 1 number", but you want to match "any 1 number, not followed or preceded by another number".

One way to do that is to use lookarounds

```
re.findall(r'(?<![0-9])[0-9](?![0-9])', s5)
```

Possible lookarounds:

```
(?<!R)S   // negative lookbehind: match S that is not preceded by R
(?<=R)S   // positive lookbehind: match S that is preceded by R
(?!R)S   // negative lookahead: match S that is not followed by R
(?=R)S   // positive lookahead: match S that is followed by R
```

Maybe a simpler solution is to use a capturing group `()`. if regex in `findall` has one capturing group, it will return list of matches withing the group instead of whole matches:

```
re.findall(r'[^0-9]([0-9])[^0-9]', s5)
```

Also note that you can replace any `0-9` with `\d` - character group of numbers

Comment: Thanks.. what's the use of the '<'  (less than) in the expression ?

Comment: I added explanation of basic lookarounds

Comment: Thanks Tomas.. i wasn't aware of that in regex.. Now its clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
k = re.findall('(?<!\S)\d(?!\S)', s5)
print(k)
```

This also works :

```
re.findall('(?<!\S)\d(?![^\s.,?!])', s5)
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas. what is the use of the '<'  (less than in this expression ?)

Comment: This means "match a digit only if there is not a non-whitespace character before it, and there is not a non-whitespace character after it".

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "The baby is 1 year old, Sri is 45 years old, Ann is 50 years old; their father, Sumo is 78 years old and their grandfather, Kris, is 100 years old"

m = re.findall('\d+',s)


for i in m:
    if int(i)<10:
        print(i)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This can be used to compare easily for any value. For ex using re.findall('(?<!\S)\d(?!\S)', s) for comparing with values less than 20 or any two digit value may fail.